# Where can I find a good written tutorial for Stargate Resistance?

Tags: stargate-resistance

I just started playing Stargate Resistance, and the game has no in-game tutorial. Where can I find a good write-up that will lead me through the basics of gameplay?

Answer (score 1):

I only played a brief bit of the demo, but it seemed to me that Stargate Resistance pulled a lot from the history of team-based FPS/3PS games. If you can't find Stargate Resistance specific walkthroughs that satisfy your needs, you may find that playing (or at least reading up on) one of the other big team-based FPS/3PS games might help you gain the vocabulary you need to better play Stargate Resistance. For instance, Valve's Team Fortress 2 is commonly seen as the current team-based FPS king, and it is known for being relatively friendly to beginners. I think a few rounds of TF2 could certainly help a Stargate Resistance player.